# How to use I18n inside Vue files in json sections

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization

I use vue.js, nuxt.js, I installed the i18n package, configured it, translation works fine, if text in a Vue file.

The Vue file has a menu that is loaded from json, which is on the same page.

It is my menu, loaded using json method:

```
   {
     id: 1,
     title: "Home",
     submenus: [
       {
         id: 1,
         title: "Home 1",
         url: "/",
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         title: "Home 2",
         url: "/home-2",
       },
       {
         id: 3,
         title: "Home 3",
         url: "/home-3",
       },
     ],
   },
```

**EDIT:**
In Vue page i add i18n:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { locales, locale, setLocale } = useI18n();
const language = computed({
    get: () => locale.value,
    set: (value) => {
        setLocale(value);
    },
});
```

And menu is:

```
const menus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Home",
    submenus: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Home 1",
        url: "/",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Home 2",
        url: "/home-2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Home 3",
        url: "/home-3",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

How i need translate `title` from `id1` and `title` from `submenus`, how i can make it correctly?

I try to make `title: "{t('main_menu'}",`, but it doesn't work, it's only display this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Composer instance `t` that comes from `useI18n()` to translate:

```js
const { t, locales, locale, setLocale } = useI18n();
```

```
title: t('main_menu')
```

Seen [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#message-translation) in the documentation.

Comment: thank you, all works, but receive 1 problem. my menu doesnt translate "by fly". i see translate only when refresh page. another text translated perfect, without refresh the page. how i can fix it, maybe you know?